# Does nth index of n sized C array contain size of it?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, garbage

I've written a C program for showing the values of an array using pointer. Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int *ptr = a;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d ", *ptr++);
    printf("%d", *ptr);
}
```

As you can see after terminating the loop, the pointer holds the memory address of a value out of the array. As it i.e. the last output is not initialized, it should be a garbage value. But, every time it is showing 5 which is the size of the array. Then, I thought the next memory address of allocated memory for array contains the size of array. But, this is not happening with double type array.

```
Output for int array : 1 1 1 1 1 5
Output for double array : 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
```

Will anyone explain the output?

Comment: You are using i++ so ptr is pointing to a an area in memory in your program  outside the array a.  Since you recompiled to change from an int to a double I can't infer why in one case you are getting a 5 and the other case a zero.  Both a double and int are store as 4 bytes with a double being a IEEE 488 floating point number.

Comment: @jdweng: 1) there is no use in further researching undefined behaviour. 2) double requires at least 64 bits, i.e. 8 octets (unless your bytes have 16 bits, which would be perfectly valid - check CHAR_BIT) 3) What is IEEE488? Typically C uses IEC 60559 (aka IEEE754) floating point. Never header about the standard you mention. Can you provide a link?

Comment: "*it should be a garbage value*" -- It **is** a garbage value. *"But, every time it is showing 5 which is the size of the array.*' -- `5` is garbage. Garbage is not required to have a different value every time you look at it; seemingly consistent garbage is still garbage. Garbage is not (necessarily) random.

Comment: It's probably running into the low-order byte of `i`, which just happens to be stored in memory after the array, and would be 5 after the loop.

Comment: I wrote wrong IEEE specification.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do invokes **Undefined Behavior**.

It's simple a coincidence and probably just the value of `i`, print the address of `i` and check. But be careful, it will not always be that way. Just declare a new variable in the program and it might change.

In the case of `double` it doesn't work because the address after the array no longer matches the address of `i`. It's what I mean when I say *Be careful*.

Comment: It can't be just a coincidence. I've run the code over 20 times. I've restarted Code Blocks IDE several times. Restarted the computer. Changed the size of the array. And still I'm getting the size at nth position.

Comment: It depends on the stack memory of the program, it will not change just because you recompile it or because you change the size of the array, it will however change if you change the program, try declaring a new `int` variable before the `for` loop and give it a random value different than `5`. Or use a differente compiler perhaps.

Comment: @ParvezMRobin: That's an artifact of how the compiler arranged objects on the stack for *this particular program*.  Your particular collection of variables just happen to get laid out in a manner where (it looks like) `i` follows the last element of the array.  A different compiler, or the same compiler with different optimization settings, may lay the variables out in a different order.  This is not a defined behavior, it really is just a coincidence.

Comment: Yes, it is. Printing memory address of i didn't work as it showed a different memory address. But when I changed the code as following

    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int a[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        int *ptr = a;
    
        for(int i = 5; i<10; i++)
            printf("%d ", *ptr++);
        printf("%d ", *ptr);
    }

the output is 1 1 1 1 1 10. So it was the value of i.

Comment: Yes the address migh be different, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001867/does-nth-index-of-n-sized-c-array-contain-size-of-it/33001896#comment53830573_33001867). But the idea is that it has to do you the layout of the program in memory, so you got it now.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a value from memory in this address. You should never access memory which is not allocated by you (In this case you are accessing 6th element, but you have declared just 5). This may lead to segmentation fault is some cases.

Comment: *segmentation fault is some cases* just -> *undefiend behavior*.

Comment: It can't be just a value from memory address. I've run the code over 20 times. I've restarted Code Blocks IDE several times. Restarted the computer. Changed the size of the array. And still I'm getting the size at nth position.

Comment: It's still a coincidence.

Comment: There are a lot of optimizations which OS does about memory management. So there is quite high chance that each time you will receive same piece of memory.

Answer (score 3):

C does not store any array metadata (including array length) anywhere, either at the beginning or the end of the array.  In the case of the integer array, the *most likely* explanation for the output is that the memory used by the variable `i` immediately follows the last element of the array, like so:

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0]
   +---+ 
   | 1 | a[1]
   +---+
   | 1 | a[2]
   +---+
   | 1 | a[3]
   +---+
   | 1 | a[4]
   +---+
i: | 5 | a[5]
   +---+
```

However, you *cannot* rely on this behavior being consistent, as you saw with changing the array type to `double`.

Attempting to read the value contained in the element one past the end of the array results in *undefined behavior*.  [Chapter and (truncated) verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
> ...
> 8  When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
> result has the type of the pointer operand...**If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
> shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated.**

For giggles, I compiled your code on my system at work, and I get the following output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

This really is just an artifact of how the compiler lays objects out in memory for this particular program.